# How to change the view controller of the uicontainerview in iOS 6 at runtime

Tags: ios

I have a UISegmentedView control with two options. This is part of a MasterViewController. Inside the MasterViewController I have two embedded view controllers, childViewController1 and childViewController2. I have a UIContainerView which is tied to childViewController1. Now I want that when I select the option 2 of the segmented control I should somehow configure the UIContainerView to use the childViewController2.

Answer (score -1):

I'm by no means an expert iOS/Obj-C developer, but I am a bit confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.

What do you mean by change the view controller? You can pass to different view controllers in viewDidLoad. These are wired up in your storyboard, and I *think* you have to call the navigation controller as well, but I'm not sure.

Either way, I don't understand what you mean by 'segmented' control. Do you have two view controllers? Are you passing data between the two? If so, you'll need to learn about delegates. If not, maybe look at the segue method. My 2 cents.